# FIFO Implementation in Inventory using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, fifo

This is basically an inventory project which tracks the "Stock In" and "Stock Out" of items through Purchase and sales respectively.

The inventory system follows FIFO Method (the items which are first purchased are always sold first). For example:

> If we purchased Item A in months January, February and March 
>   When a customer comes we give away items purchased during January 
>   only when the January items are over we starts giving away February items and so on

So I have to show here the total stock in my hand and the split up so that I can see the total cost incurred.

Actual table data:

[image: Actual table data]

The result set I need to obtain:

[image: What the result set is meant to be]

My client insists that I should not use Cursor, so is there any other way of doing so?

Comment: which SQL Server version, 2012 maybe?

Comment: A cursor solution will be by far the most efficient solution then. What's wrong with the cursors, anyway?

Comment: @dean - a lot is wrong with the cursors - http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them Sure there are situations where they could/should be used, but this hardly one of those

Comment: With windowing functions as they were in 2008, cursor will outperform any set-based solution for this particular problem (somehow I guess that real world data is not so clean). Feel free to prove me wrong :)

Comment: A recursive CTE could do the trick: [Recursive Queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx). BTW what is PK of this table?

Comment: @Harish Can you explain a bit detailed your requirements? How do you get two rows with `Item A` in `WH1` with same price in results?

Comment: Say it like i purchased item A on Monday as price was 10.00, then i again purchased on tuesday for same price, its just purchase and sales, some times price goes up some time not, i need to compute the inventory value thats it!!

Comment: @Harish - How is the table sorted? You mention months, but I don't see them there. If my understanding is correct, then the sort order is pretty important..

Comment: sorry there is a date field and i have sorted it using date ...

Comment: can you include it in the sample data as well please?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, if I understand the requirement correctly, the `Price` in row 1 of your results should be `300.00` not `500.00` ?

Comment: wow no cursor, i want to see the answer... in my opinion this case need a loop. i have a FIFO query but it use CURSOR or use loop in the code. i really want to see this question answered...thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As some comment already said a CTE can solve this

```
with cte as (
select item, wh, stock_in, stock_out, price, value
     , row_number() over (partition by item, wh order by item, wh) as rank
from   myTable)
select a.item, a.wh
     , a.stock_in - coalesce(b.stock_out, 0) stock
     , a.price
     , a.value - coalesce(b.value, 0) value
from cte a
     left join cte b on a.item = b.item and a.wh = b.wh and a.rank = b.rank - 1
where a.stock_in - coalesce(b.stock_out, 0) > 0
```

If the second "Item B" has the wrong price (the IN price is 25, the OUT is 35).
[SQL 2008 fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0498/1)

Just for fun, with sql server 2012 and the introduction of the LEAD and LAG function the same thing is possible in a somewhat easier way

```
with cte as (
select item, wh, stock_in
     , coalesce(LEAD(stock_out) 
                OVER (partition by item, wh order by item, wh), 0) stock_out
     , price, value
     , coalesce(LEAD(value) 
                OVER (partition by  item, wh order by item, wh), 0) value_out
from   myTable)
select item
     , wh
     , (stock_in - stock_out) stock
     , price
     , (value - value_out) value
from   cte
where  (stock_in - stock_out) > 0
```

[SQL2012 fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad6f1/5)

**Update**
ATTENTION -> To use the two query before this point the data need to be in the correct order.

To have the details with more then one row per day you need something reliable to order the row with the same date, like a date column with time, an autoincremental ID or something down the same line, and it's not possible to use the query already written because they are based on the position of the data.

A better idea is to split the data in IN and OUT, order it by item, wh and data, and apply a rank on both data, like this:

```
SELECT d_in.item
     , d_in.wh
     , d_in.stock_in - coalesce(d_out.stock_out, 0) stock
     , d_in.price
     , d_in.value - coalesce(d_out.value, 0) value
FROM   (SELECT item, wh, stock_in, price, value
             , rank = row_number() OVER 
               (PARTITION BY item, wh ORDER BY item, wh, date)
        FROM   myTable
        WHERE  stock_out = 0) d_in
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT item, wh, stock_out, price, value
             , rank = row_number() OVER 
               (PARTITION BY item, wh ORDER BY item, wh, date)
        FROM   myTable
        WHERE  stock_in = 0) d_out
       ON d_in.item = d_out.item AND d_in.wh = d_out.wh 
      AND d_in.rank = d_out.rank
WHERE d_in.stock_in - coalesce(d_out.stock_out, 0) > 0
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46c5f/1)

But this query is **NOT** completely reliable, the order of data in the same order group is not stable.

I haven't change the query to recalculate the price if the IN.price is different from the OUT.price

Comment: hmm for the inventory value probably like this (a.stock_in - coalesce(b.stock_out, 0)) * a.price) as 'Value'

Comment: @cyan the Value is money so (Value_IN - Value_OUT) is probably correct, is the price that need some calc, like (Value_IN - Value_OUT) / (stock_in - stock_out)

Comment: I wish I was clever enough to wrap my mind around TSQL solutions like this. +1

Comment: @Serpiton we will have more than one in and out per day

Comment: @Serpiton We need the details we can't group the data by details

Answer (score 1):

If cursors aren't an option, a [SQLCLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) might be. This way you could obtain the raw data into [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) objects, manipulate / sort it using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) and set the resulting data as the procedure's output. Not only this will give you what you want, it may even turn up being much easier than trying to do the same in pure T-SQL, depending on your programming background.

Comment: I want to note that using SQLCLR opens up a security flaw for those who are considering it.

Comment: @BilliD There are three levels of security an SQLCLR assembly can be set to. On the SAFE level, which IMHO is sufficient for the problem at hand, there shouldn't be any security issues.