# FIFO stock inventory valuation

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am using sql server 2014..My stock transaction table is like this.

```
declare @Stock table (Item char(3) not null,[Date] datetime not null,TxnType varchar(3) not null,Qty int not null,Price decimal(10,2) null)
insert into @Stock(Item ,  [Date] ,        TxnType, Qty,  Price) values
('ABC','20120401','IN',    200, 750.00),
('ABC','20120405','OUT',   100 ,null  ),
('ABC','20120410','IN',     50, 700.00),
('ABC','20120416','IN',     75, 800.00),
('ABC','20120425','OUT',   175, null  ),
('XYZ','20120402','IN',    150, 350.00),
('XYZ','20120408','OUT',   120 ,null  ),
('XYZ','20120412','OUT',    10 ,null  ),
('XYZ','20120424','IN',     90, 340.00);
```

I need to calculate below 2 cases at every monthe end.

1. Stock valuation of the  remaining quantity

OUTPUT :

Stock valuation of the stock data

```
Item  Qty      Value
ABC   50    40000.00
XYZ   110   37400.00
```

Please help me to get the solution in FIFO

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions, which makes it less likely that anyone will answer.

Comment: Do you _have_ to do this in SQL?  SQL is designed to read and write data. Complex rules like this are much more suitable for an application layer,

Comment: thanks @gordon..i have edited the question...

Comment: @stanley need solution in Sql only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FIFO Implementation in Inventory using SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936112/fifo-implementation-in-inventory-using-sql)

Comment: @DeanOC I don't believe it is a duplicate because this requires not only a partition based on the column Item but Sum (adding/subtracting) based on the value of another column. Where as that post only Sums up two different columns values together.

Comment: This was a learning experience for me on how to do a case within a Sum aggregation.

Comment: Thanks @ Edward for yor answer...is it possible to  same can achieved using window function?pls let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Item, FinalQty as [Final Qty], CurrPrice*FinalQty as [Current Value] from (
 select Item, Sum(Case When TxnType='OUT' Then -Qty Else Qty End) as FinalQty ,
        (Select Top 1 Price from @Stock where Price is not null and s.Item=Item order by Date Desc) as CurrPrice
 from @Stock s
 group by Item ) n
```

Comment: @Thanks..it is working fine..if posible pls give a solution using window functions

Comment: An function (like sum) with the over (partition by...) is considered windowing. which is what I tried doing but that cannot have conditions pressed on it like in your case with the IN adds and OUT subtracts. Look here [Windowing by 'Over'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)